# Как добавить многоуровневый индекс с помощью цикла?

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

допустим есть массив

```
$arr = [];

for ($i = 3; $i > 0; $i--) {
    // здесь нужно создать дерево с последовательностью из вопроса
}
```

нужно в этом цикле создать массив `$arr` вот такого вида

```
$arr = [ 3 => [ 2 => [ 1 => ["any value"]]]];
```

я не знаю как добавлять очередной вложенный индекс в таких ситуациях.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

достаточно записать цикл в прямом порядке

```
$arr = ["any value"];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $arr = [$i => $arr];
}

print_r($arr);
```

---

```
Array (
  [3] => Array (
     [2] => Array (
        [1] => Array (
           [0] => any value
         )
      )
   )
 )
```

---

в вашей постановке будет несколько сложнее:

```
$arr = [];
$tmp = &$arr;
for ($i = 3; $i > 0; $i--){
    $tmp[$i] = [];
    $tmp = &$tmp[$i];
}
$tmp = ["any value"];

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: благодарю, а не могли бы помочь написать код с помощью такого же цикла пройтись по вот этому только то созданному массиву

Comment: @perfect добавил код с обратным циклом, в принципе он обходит массив.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: со  2ого варианта мозг немножечко взорвался, спасибо

Comment: @Peresada создаем ключ и двигаем ссылку на него, все ж просто вроде :)

Comment: @teran да, это в итоге ясно, но все равно тяжело для понимания особенно строка после самого цикла :)

Comment: @perfect тогда, думаю, вы знаете где ткнуть галку :)

Comment: @teran все нормально, я закрываю все вопросы которые можно закрыть. просто код дописываю пока голова свежая. большое спасибо у вас очень исчерпывающий ответ